# Invalid Outside Procedure for range.copy function

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am brand new to VBA Excel coding and I am trying to perform a simple range.copy function to automate copying and pasting values from one worksheet to another. The following is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Worksheets("Consolidated YTD").Range("A1:AF144").copy Worksheets("Consolidated PriorYTD").Range("A1")
```

I keep getting a compile error for invalid outside procedure. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is the case? Thanks!

Comment: You're missing an `End Sub` statement after copying

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you explain the steps to insert the end sub? I tried to copy it directly but it did not work. As I said I am brand new at this. Thanks!

Comment: See the reply from @barneyos

Answer (score 0):

You must close your sub adding End Sub:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Worksheets("Consolidated YTD").Range("A1:AF144").copy Worksheets("Consolidated PriorYTD").Range("A1")
End Sub
```